# My AsyncTask not getting cancelled android

Tags: android, asynchronous, background

I am working on a task that calls my `AsyncTask` , once the `async task` is executed , I wait for 20 seconds to get the data from server , if it is still loading I am cancelling it (handling timeout)

```
public void handleServerTimeOut() {
        getStore = new GetStore();
        getStore.execute();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (getStore != null && getStore.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                    boolean result = getStore.cancel(true);
                    Log.e(TAG, "  handleServerTimeOut() reached 20 seconds");
                    Log.e(TAG, "" + result);
                }
            }
        }, 20000);
    }
```

AsyncTask

```
class GetStore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String status, message;
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        String buildingIdGuest, buildingIdUser, finalBuildingID;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            if (isCancelled()) {
                return;
            } else {
                buildingIdUser = utilClass.getSharePerefernce(getActivity(), KEY_BUILDING_ID_USER, "");
                buildingIdGuest = utilClass.getSharePerefernce(getActivity(), KEY_BUILDING_ID_GUEST, "");
                if (buildingIdUser.equals("0") || buildingIdUser.equals("")) {
                    finalBuildingID = buildingIdGuest;
                } else {
                    finalBuildingID = buildingIdUser;
                }


                error_flag = 0;
                gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                error_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                img_no_internet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                img_no_results.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                img_server_error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Getting nearby stores ...");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                try {

                    jsonObj = userFunction.getStores(OS, MAKE, MODEL, finalBuildingID);

                    Log.e(TAG, jsonObj.toString());
                    status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                    message = jsonObj.getString("message");

                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                        jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            gridModel = new GridModel();
                            gridModel.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                            gridModel.setStore_name(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                            gridModel.setImage_name(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_name"));
                            gridListData.add(gridModel);


                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "******  =  " + gridListData.toString());

                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid parameters")) {
                        error_flag = 2;
                        Log.e(TAG, "invalid parameters");
                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("no stores")) {
                        error_flag = 3;
                        Log.e(TAG, "No Data");
                    }

                    Log.e(TAG, "****** status " + status);
                    return String.valueOf(jsonObj);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    error_flag = 1; // Handling server timeout.
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Network Error");
                error_flag = 1;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);

            Log.e(TAG, "  **** error **** " + error_flag);

            if (error_flag == 1) {
                gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                error_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img_no_internet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (error_flag == 2) {
                gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                error_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img_server_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtError.setText(message);
            } else if (error_flag == 3) {
                gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                error_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img_no_results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), gridListData);
            gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
            if ((progressDialog != null) && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also wanted to cancel my `AsyncTask` when the user cancels the `ProgressDialog`

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `isCancelled()` only once in your `AsyncTask` - in the `onPreExecute()` method. At the time you call `cancel()` on your task instance, this check has already been evaluated and this is why the async task is still completing and updating the UI.

To deal with the issue, I suggest you include more checks for cancellation, using the `isCancelled()` method. One obvious place to include such a check is in the `onPostExecute()` method, right before you update the UI. You could also include a check before making the actual request to the server, after receiving the response, etc.